# unable to achiev the 2nd condition in if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a slider on my homepage...  This statement `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-narrow.php'); ?>`  brings me to get a slider..

I found the code below in my `home.php`:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featcontent', true ) == "Yes" ) { ?>
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-vids.php'); ?>
            <?php } ?
```

I am pretty sure if I change that condition, I'm able to display a slider...

Actually in that 'if' statement, I need 2 conditions: a) Checking Homepage and b)it shud met a condtion that value of 'post_featcontent' equals to "Narrow Width Featured Content Slider"...

I tried as below:

```
if ( is_front_page() && get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featcontent', true ) == "Narrow Width Featured Content Slider" )
```

I was able to succeed with a), BUT am unable to achieve condition for b)  (BTW, it's a WordPress.., but it's just a PHP doubt I feel..)

Could anyone help please..?

**EDITED:**

```
$meta_boxes = array(

        "layout" => array(
            "name" => "layout",
            "type" => "select",
            "title" => __("Page Layout", "solostream"),
            "description" => __("Select a layout for this page/post.", "solostream"),


        "post_featcontent" => array(
            "name" => "post_featcontent",
            "type" => "select",
            "title" => __("Add Featured Articles/Posts to This Post", "solostream"),
            "description" => __("If you'd like to add featured articles/posts to the top of this post, make your selection below.", "solostream"),
            "options" => array(
                    "No", 
                    "Full Width Featured Content Slider", 
                    "Narrow Width Featured Content Slider")),

);
```

Comment: what did you get as print_r() for get_post_meta(...)?

Comment: Check your database with PHPmyAdmin or whatever you use, check the wp_postmeta table for what the value of post_featcontent is... or print_r it. Chances are the value of this custom meta is not what you think it is.

Comment: @toxicate20 & @ShawnWernig +1. I suggested to do a similar thing when the OP asked the same exact question in [stackoverflow.com/questions/13498265/retreive-value-from-array-of-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498265/retreive-value-from-array-of-array), which is now `closed`

Comment: hi, I edited now.. could u pls again look into this...?

Answer (score -1):

change your if statement to include another set of brackets

```
if ( (is_front_page()) && (get_post_meta( $postid, 'post_featcontent', true) == "Narrow Width Featured Content Slider") 
   ){
```

essentially you want to separate each condition to meet a certain criteria,

ie: if((this=this) && (this=this))

where both conditions need to be true in order to continue,
to do this you wrap each condition with Parentheses, then encapsulate both with another set of parentheses.